# Reading an array following a 2 level string.split

Tags: vb.net

Newbie question.  I can't figure this out.

I have string "48,1;49,2;50,0" which I have split using :

```
Dim splitAtSemiColon() As String = strPatientMed.Split(";"c)
Dim result() = splitAtSemiColon.Select(Function(x) x.Split(","c)).ToArray()

In the Visual studio interface, I can see that this results in:
Result(0) contains (0) = "48" and (1) = "1"
Result(1) contains (0) = "49" and (1) = "2"
Result(2) contains (0) = "50" and (1) = "0"
```

But how do I loop to read this array using code i.e. how do I read the (0) and (1) portion of each result item?

Thanks all!

Comment: You can also do this: `Dim splitAtSemiColon() As String = strPatientMed.Split({",", ";"}, StringSplitOptions.None)`. Maybe it's simpler (?).

Comment: You can loop through `Result` like you would any other array. And access `.First` and `.Last` on the element within it.

Comment: Or `dim result = strPatientMed.Split(";"c).Select(Function(str) str.Split(","c)).Select(Function(arr) New With {.Num = CInt(arr(0)), .Value = CInt(arr(1))}).ToList()`, so you have `result(0).Num` and `result(0).Value` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Sub Main()
    Dim strPatientmed = "48,1;49,2;50,0"
    Dim splitAtSemiColon() As String = strPatientMed.Split(";"c)
    Dim result() = splitAtSemiColon.Select(Function(x) x.Split(","c)).ToArray()

    'Result is an Array of arrays, each inner array has only 2 elements (first & last)
    For Each element In result
        'For each <array> in result
        'result(0) -> <element> -> [48|1] 
        '<element>.First = 48 | <element>.Last = 1
        Console.WriteLine($"Before comma: {element.First} | After comma: {element.Last}")
    Next
End Sub
```

Result

```
Before comma: 48 | After comma: 1
Before comma: 49 | After comma: 2
Before comma: 50 | After comma: 0
```

Comment: The "For Each element In result" statement is throwing an exception because element is not defined.  I tried defining it as string, object and integer with no success.

Comment: It would be a String()  -- an array of String

Comment: Got it!  BTW, can such an array be sorted as a function of {element.First}?

Comment: Use `.OrderBy`...although you should cast the string to an integer if you plan on sorting